# Something along the lines of Wanda the Fish

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, fortune

So, I've been thinking about creating a bash version of a fortune teller on the model of Wanda, but with different figures. I mean: a script that makes you write down your question of the day. The response-quote is given by a character randomly extracted from a set of, let's say, 6 fellows. I'm planning to match like 20 quotes with each character, whose features can be found in a small manual that briefly explains their bio. Any suggestion or advice on how to set up this idea? Of course this script will be run in the terminal, for the moment.
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mmmmh, something like this?

```py
#!/usr/bin/env ipython3
#
# birb-fortune.ipy
# --------------------------------
# snippet released under AGPLv3
# --------------------------------
#

birb = """
 /\_/\\
((@v@))
():::()
 VV-VV
"""

print(birb)
!fortune
```